# redirection http to https asp/iis

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Below is my web.config file. I want automatic redirection of http url to https. I tried the follwing but it is not working.
IIS7 with SSL Required checked in SSL settings.
Can anyone help please.
Thanks

```
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.webServer">
        <sectionGroup name="rewrite">
            <section name="rewriteMaps" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
            <section name="rules" overrideModeDefault="Allow" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^(.*)$" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
    <defaultDocument>
        <files>
            <add value="index.asp" />
        </files>
    </defaultDocument>       
</system.webServer>
<system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off" />     
    <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" />
</system.web>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncheck the "Require SSL"-- for the redirect to work, you have to accept the initial request on HTTP first.

**EDIT**

Second point.  You're selecting input based on HTTPS.  You need to negate the condition like this:

```
<conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" negate="true" />
</conditions>
```

Comment: Are there any setting in IIS7 which are not allowing the rewrite rule to work??